# RaspberryPi 2 and latest version of mono

Tags: pi-2, mono

Last night I reinstalled my Raspberry Pi 2 model B with the latest version of Raspbian (Jessie). All went well, but when I tried to install mono by following these [instructions](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux), the installation failed.

```
dpkg: error processing package monodoc-browser (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-cil
 libgtk2.0-cil
 libglade2.0-cil
 libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-core2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-util2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil
 libnunit-cil-dev
 libmono-cil-dev
 libwebkit1.1-cil
 mono-devel
 monodoc-browser
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running mono gives me just the following feedback: "illegal instruction".

I never had problems with installing mono on my Pi but maybe it is due to the fact that the latest version of mono is not compatible anymore with ARMv6 architecture of my Raspberry Pi 2. However, I cannot find this information on the website of mono. Mid 2016 it still installed fine on other raspberry pi 2 models.

Do I just need to install an older version from the archive? If yes, [which one](https://download.mono-project.com/archive/)?

Comment: On the page you linked to, there are several different instructions for installing, which one did you use? [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982959/how-to-install-mono-4-0-1-on-debian-8)

Comment: @jogco I just used the first one, i'll try to add the three other repositories as well and will try again. I'll let you know this weekend

Comment: Be sure to read the whole _Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives_ section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think architecture is getting in the way here. If you exactly followed the instructions on the site, undo *all of them*. I'm sure they're for x86/x64 (your everyday PCs). The Pi is using ARM (comparable to mobile phones).

Best bet would be to reinstall Raspbian.

After that, simply run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

to update the system, then

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

You should have `mono` after the installation completes.

Comment: Thx! this worked.. don't forget to install first the package apt-transport-https and after that mono-complete

Comment: but be aware that this is only going to install mono version 3.2.8

Comment: I was able to install mono 4.8 on Rpi 3 and run an console app which was compiled on VS2017 (4.5.2), which did not run before. These instruction was a great help: https://forums.homeseer.com/showthread.php?t=183916

Comment: FYI: mono-project has broken/non-existent packages for jessie, which is probably the reason for this whole problem. However, adding the wheezy package list works: `echo 'deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono.list`